# Make one website look as if it were in a folder of a different website

Tags: iis

This concerns use of IIS version 10 on an Intranet server.

For the sake of this example, I created three "hello world" IIS Websites (Site0, Site1, and Site2). All three are hosted on the same Intranet server (`RMG-SAND`). It's easy enough to make and test the websites as individual applications. Sites 0, 1, and 2 each have different MVC applications. *They are not the same application.*

- Site 0 is `http://rmg-sand/`
- Site 1 is `http://rmg-sand:81/`
- Site 2 is `http://rmg-sand:82/`

**I have been requested to provide the illusion that the three sites are actually part of the same site.** So even though on IIS these remain distinct sites with separate physical paths, I am requested to make it so the URLs act like this.

- Site 0 is `http://Site0/`
- Site 1 is `http://Site0/Site1/`
- Site 2 is `http://Site0/Site2/`

As the same time, I still need to be able to use the true URLs in code, so both of these would work as intended and point to the correct resource.

- Site 0 is reached by `http://Site0/` or `http://rmg-sand/`
- Site 1 is reached by `http://Site0/Site1/` or `http://rmg-sand:81/`
- Site 2 is reached by `http://Site0/Site2/` or `http://rmg-sand:82/`

As far as people using a browser are concerned, however, they would only see and use the "everything on the same site" style and any use of the "ports" style would work correctly but immediately rewrite to the "everything on the same site" style.

How would I go about achieving this illusion?

I have searched for articles and examples, but so far I have not seen anything matching my scenario, most likely because I am not using the terms used in the articles I really need to look at.

If it is possible, what technique(s) would I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have it worked out. This is what I did to make this "hello world" scenario work. I haven't managed to break it yet. Whether it is the *best* way to solve the problem, I do not know. In the end it was the sequence of two operations that gave me the needed result: (1) adding "Application" to `Site0` and (2) use of "URL Redirect" in Site1 and Site2 to redirect to the correct Site0 "Application".

**First,** create Applications to Site0 to represent "folders" for each website you need to add. (My mistake was trying it as "Virtual Folder").

1. Right-click "Site0" and select `Add Application`: Alias is `Site1` and physical path is the same path used for "Site1".
2. Right-click "Site0" and select `Add Application`: Alias is `Site2` and physical path is the same path used for "Site2".

**Next,** in Site1 and Site2, you need to use the "URL Rewrite" https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite to add a redirect rule in each site. I used the IIS Manager GUI.

For Site1:

1. Click "URL Rewrite".
2. Add new rule: `Inbound Rules > Blank Rule`
3. Name: "Redirect rmg-sand:81 to rmg-sand/Site1"
4. Pattern: `.*`
5. Conditions: `{HTTP_HOST}` matches pattern `^rmg-sand:81$`
6. Redirect to: `http://rmg-sand/Site1/{R:0}`.
7. Redirect type: `Permanent`

For Site2:

1. Click "URL Rewrite".
2. Add new rule: `Inbound Rules > Blank Rule`
3. Name: "Redirect rmg-sand:82 to rmg-sand/Site2"
4. Pattern: `.*`
5. Conditions: `{HTTP_HOST}` matches pattern `^rmg-sand:82$`
6. Redirect to: `http://rmg-sand/Site1/{R:0}`.
7. Redirect type: `Permanent`

I have tested clicking links within each of the sites (e.g., `http://rmg-sand/Site2/Home/Contact` and `http://rmg-sand:82/Home/Contact`) and it appears to work correctly. Both links point to the same page, but the user sees the "all in one site" version of the link.